# how can i fix this error about ajax post return 415 code

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, http-status-code-415

I use ajax to post the data:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#l").click(function(){
                if($("#number").val().length <= 5 || $("#password").val().length <= 5){
                    $("#show").show();
                } else {
                    $("#show").hide();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"index/judement",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    contentType:"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                    data:JSON.stringify({
                        number:$("#number").val(),
                        password:$("#password").val()
                    }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var a = data.message;
                        if(a=="true"){
                            alert(data.message);
                        } else {
                            $("#show").show();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                      alert("error");
                    }
                });}
            });
        })
    </script>
```

but it return 415 code for me! so I search many method in the morning. Finally, I add this code in my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
            <list>
                <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and it work! But when I close the IDE and restart, it get error!!!oh my god!

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jsonHttpMessageConverter' while setting bean property 'messageConverters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonHttpMessageConverter': Failed to introspect bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter$Indenter
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonHttpMessageConverter': Failed to introspect bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter$Indenter
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter$Indenter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter$Indenter
```

now, what the hell?

Comment: I undo this code and recode...and it work again........I can 't believe that...

Comment: But this is the first time I run mine :(